# R: How to tell where in a word a repeating letters appears in order to add to a dataframe

Tags: r

I'm trying to detect how many words in a vector have a repeating letter and count the number of times that it is repeated in other words also, adding it to a data frame each time the repeated letters are encountered.
For example: `x = c("google", "blood", "street")`
the data frame will appear as

```
         letter   n
1            oo   2
2            ee   1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match repeating letters using regex and match using `stringr::str_match_all()`:

```
library(stringr)
as.data.frame(table(unlist(sapply(str_match_all(x, regex("([A-Za-z]{1})\\1")), `[`, , 1))))

  Var1 Freq
1   ee    1
2   oo    2
```

Answer (score 0):

One option in `base R` is to convert to `raw`, use `rle` to get the run-length-encoding, subset only the elements having `lengths` greater than 1, reconvert to character and get the frequency count with `table`

```
stack(table(sapply(x, function(y) rawToChar(with(rle(charToRaw(y)), 
        rep(values[lengths > 1], lengths[lengths > 1]))))))[2:1]
#   ind values
#1  ee      1
#2  oo      2
```

---

Or with `str_extract` (assuming there is only a single repeated substring)

```
library(stringr)
stack(table(str_extract(x, "(\\w)\\1")))[2:1]
#   ind values
#1  ee      1
#2  oo      2
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
str_extract_all(x, "(\\w)\\1") %>% 
    tibble(letter = .) %>%
    unnest(c(letter)) %>%
    count(letter)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the last solution, when you pass ```letter = .``` as an argument to tibble(), is that just a place holder for the value piped in from str_extract()?

Comment: @CourtMiddleton Here the `.` is the output from the `str_extract_all` which is captured to create a column in the `tbl_df` created by `tibble`.  Yes, it is the value piped from str_extract

Answer (score 0):

Another base R solution using `regmatches` + `table`

```
dfout <- as.data.frame(table(unlist(regmatches(x,gregexpr("(\\w)\\1+",x)))))
```

which gives

```
> dfout
  Var1 Freq
1   ee    1
2   oo    2
```